# Changing function argument to global variable causes unexpected results

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

I'm solving a backtracking problem. I have to construct a permutation of length n in such a way that the sum of each adjacent elements are prime. The permutation is circular, the last element is adjacent to first element. Note that all valid permutations should start with 1.

```
void recurse(int i, int prev, int n, vector<int> prime_ring) {
  if (i == n) {
    prime_ring.insert(prime_ring.begin(), 1);
    
    if (!is_prime[prime_ring.back() + 1])
      return;
      for (auto data : prime_ring)
        cout << data << " ";
      cout << "\n";
    
    prime_ring.clear();
    return;
  }
  for (int next = 2; next <= n; next++) {
    if (!seen[next] && is_prime[prev + next]) {
       prime_ring.push_back(next);
       seen[next] = true;
       recurse(i + 1, next, n, prime_ring);
       seen[next] = false;
       prime_ring.pop_back();
      
    }

  }
}
```

The above code generates the wanted permutations correctly. For example for n = 4. Permutations should be

```
1 2 3 4 
1 4 3 2 



void recurse(int i, int prev, int n) {
  if (i == n) {
    prime_ring.insert(prime_ring.begin(), 1);
    
    if (!is_prime[prime_ring.back() + 1])
      return;
      for (auto data : prime_ring)
        cout << data << " ";
      cout << "\n";
    
    prime_ring.clear();
    return;
  }
  for (int next = 2; next <= n; next++) {
    if (!seen[next] && is_prime[prev + next]) {
       prime_ring.push_back(next);
       seen[next] = true;
       recurse(i + 1, next, n);
       seen[next] = false;
       prime_ring.pop_back();
      
    }

  }
}
```

Changing `prime_ring` to a global vector, results in runtime error. This problem happened to me many times, I failed to realise what's wrong. I'm not aware of the difference between global vector vs function argument vector.

Comment: Every time you call `recurse` a new copy of `prime_ring` is created (pass by value).  With a global `prime_ring` there is only one.  So the algorithms are different.

Comment: "Changing prime_ring to a global vector, results in runtime error." Then don't do that. You already have a working solution.

Comment: `prime_ring.clear();` Why do you clear the state when you found a solution?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Actually my first approach was the global one. That's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not aware of the difference between global vector vs function argument vector.

The difference is that when you pass a `vector` as a parameter, the `vector` is copied. On the other hand when you use a global variable, there is only one `vector.

The solution here is to not use a global variable since you have a working function.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are on the line

```
recurse(i + 1, next, n);
```

where `i == n - 1`

Suppose when you go into the `recurse` function, `is_prime[prime_ring.back() + 1]` is `true`.

Then you call `prime_ring.clear();`, and returns.

Afterwards, you call `prime_ring.pop_back();`

What happens if you try to `pop_back()` from an empty vector? Well, bad things can happen (namely, [Undefined Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior))